# Why implemention using AbstractList is faster?

Tags: java

I am doing this leetcode problem https://leetcode.com/problems/all-paths-from-source-to-target/

and found that my answer is slower than the fastest solution, the fastest solution is below

```
public List<List<Integer>> allPathsSourceTarget(int[][] graph) {
    
    return new java.util.AbstractList<List<Integer>>() {
        
        List<List<Integer>> allPaths = null;
        
        Deque<Integer> path = new ArrayDeque<>();
        
        @Override 
        public List<Integer> get(int i) {
            return allPaths.get(i);
        }
        
        @Override 
        public int size() {
            if (allPaths == null) {
                allPaths = new ArrayList<>();
                dfs(0);
            }
            return allPaths.size();
        }
        
        private void dfs(int curr) {
            path.addLast(curr);
            if (curr == graph.length-1) {
                allPaths.add(new ArrayList<>(path));
            } else {
                for (int v : graph[curr]) {
                    dfs(v);
                }
            }
            path.pollLast();
        }
    };
}
```

I think maybe is my solution passing too much parameter to DFS method,

so I change my answer to like the fastest solution like below

```
Deque<Integer> path = new ArrayDeque<>();
List<List<Integer>> allPaths = null;
int[][] graphOOO = null;

public List<List<Integer>> allPathsSourceTarget(int[][] graph) {
    graphOOO = graph;
    allPaths = new ArrayList<>();
    dfsV2(0);
    return allPaths;
}

private void dfsV2(int curr) {
    path.addLast(curr);
    if (curr == graphOOO.length -1) {
        allPaths.add(new ArrayList<>(path));
    }
    else {
        for (int v : graphOOO[curr]) {
            dfsV2(v);
        }
    }
    path.pollLast();
}
```

but still my solution is slower than implement in AbstractList, i cannot figure out why

Comment: What exact two points is the time being measured between? Do you see that the fastest solution does no work until `size()` is called on the returned `List`?

Comment: but eventually it still need to work, and do same thing, but it's faster, i still don't know why

Comment: Precisely which two points is the time being measured between?

Comment: leetcode submit  to measure two solution time

Comment: Maybe they are measuring the time it takes for `allPathsSourceTarget` to return a reference to a `List`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question a few times, and today I got really stuck because my solution was no different from the fastest one except that I did not use a custom List implementation.

I bet custom List hack tricks leetcode evaluation engine by making actual code execution "lazy". So in your case, `allPathsSourceTarget(int[][] graph)` executes instantly, resulting in around `0 ms` time. All the heavy work is done afterwards when leetcode compares actual and expected results, but (probably, it's my guess) this time is not considered a Runtime.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).